# Sphinx extended match mode

Tags: php, symfony, sphinx

I'm using a sphinx bundle (timewasted SphinxSearchBundle) in a symfony 2 app (https://github.com/timewasted/Search-SphinxsearchBundle) (based on the PHP API)

it works great as long as I don't try to use the SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED.

Here's a code sample

```
$sphinxSearch = $this->get('search.sphinxsearch.search');
$sphinxSearch->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$searchResults = $sphinxSearch->search("@typemesure_id 2", $index);
```

But the result is always empty, and it seems that my field (@typemesure_id) is considered as a word :

```
  'words' => 
    array
      'typemesure_id' => 
        array
          'docs' => string '0' (length=1)
          'hits' => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array
          'docs' => string '4169' (length=4)
          'hits' => string '5714' (length=4)
```

Does anyone konws whats wrong in my request ?
Can anyone post an exemple of working extended query working with this bundle?

My goal is to get a condition like "@(user1,user2,user3) 15"

Thanks for your help

Notes:
the SPH_MATCH_ALL & SPH_MATCH_ANY are working fine.
The setFilter() method is also working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the function defition...

```
public function search($query, array $indexes, array $options = array(), $escapeQuery = true)
```

It will automaticlly escape the query, so the @ will be getting escaped. Need to pass false as fourth param

Comment: I'm so shamefull... Thanks a Lot!